# Is it possible to access web services directly from address bar in React PWA?

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, react-router-dom

I'm working on a React web app that was converted to a PWA and it works fine and all. But when I try to call a web service (something like https://www.somewebsite.com/api/someController?parametersHere) directly by typing in the browser's address bar, it returns a blank screen and nothing happens. Do I need to change something in the manifests or add some listener to bypass the one that's stopping the routes that have "/api/" from triggering the web services?

I am reading about the manifest one where I add a scope, but not sure what that should look like but adding it the way like below rendered some warning in Applications tab in the browser console.

```
{
  "short_name": "MyApp",
  "name": "MyApp",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "logo.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "/",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff",
  "scope": "/api/"
}
```

It resulted in this warning.

[image]

I also added a routing in react-router-dom that would listen to "/api/" in the off chance that it might do the trick, but it didn't have any effect either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still haven't found the main culprit for the issue in question, but I did found a workaround for the issue. First, I added a new `Route` component in routes.tsx that will call another React component where I triggered a webservice call via redux-saga.